# jQuery find element with next element of specific type

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have "components" containing different input elements. These components have a checkbox that allows the user to toggle enable/disable on elements. This is the code that currently disables inputs and selects.

```
 $(".activeComponentToggle input:checkbox").on("change", function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $(this).closest("div.component").addClass("activeComponentWell");
                    $(this).closest("div.component").removeClass("inactiveComponentWell");
                    $(this).closest("div.component").find("input.form-control").prop('disabled', false);
                    $(this).closest("div.component").find("select.form-control").prop('disabled', false);
                } else {
                    $(this).closest("div.component").addClass("inactiveComponentWell");
                    $(this).closest("div.component").removeClass("activeComponentWell");
                    $(this).closest("div.component").find("input.form-control").prop('disabled', true);
                    $(this).closest("div.component").find("select.form-control").prop('disabled', true);
                }
            });
```

Now i also have this kind of HTML element

```
<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepickerRanged11">
<input type="text" id="datepickerRanged811" class="form-control">
<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span></div>
```

To disable this element i need to unbind click of the span `unbind("click");`

How can i do this? If the next() element of input is a span i need to unbind it.

Comment: You can use nextAll() and you can specify the type of element you're looking for. for span: nextAll('span:first'), similarly for prevAll()

Comment: As an aside, I'd suggest you read about [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) and replace 8 calls to `$(this).closest("div.component")` with one.  You also may want to learn about [jQuery chaining](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/).

Comment: @KamleshKushwaha that works, but only for the first element with a span.

Comment: If you need all span elements, then you can use nextAll('span'). It will select all successive span elements

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you can DRY up your code by caching the selector. Secondly, I wouldn't unbind the click handler for the span, as it will make it a pain when you need to re-attach it. Instead I would use a `data` attribute to indicate whether the `span` click is blocked or not. Something like this:

```
$(".activeComponentToggle input:checkbox").on("change", function () {
    var $component = $(this).closest("div.component");
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $component
            .addClass("activeComponentWell")    
            .removeClass("inactiveComponentWell");
            .find("input.form-control").prop('disabled', false).end()
            .find("select.form-control").prop('disabled', false).end()
            .find('span.input-group-addon').data('disabled', false)
    }
    else {
        $component
            .addClass("inactiveComponentWell")
            .removeClass("activeComponentWell")
            .find("input.form-control").prop('disabled', true).end()
            .find("select.form-control").prop('disabled', true).end()
            .find('span.input-group-addon').data('disabled', true)

    }
});
```

Then in the `span` click handler:

```
$('span.input-group-addon').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).data('disabled')) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, good answer. I'm running into some problems right now, what i want to disable it the bootstrap datetimerpicker, example code here : http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/